# Update Dataframe values by using another dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing 1000 rows and 50 columns. I have a second dataframe that contains 10 rows and 2 columns. The first columns is the value of that column in old dataframe and second column contains the new value.

I want to replace ALL the values in a particular column in the original dataframe with the values from the second dataframe.

I thought about merge concat and join but none of them would work since you are replacing/updating values in a particular column rather than adding new columns.

Let the first dataframe be df1 and the column name whose certain rows have to be updated be 'old_column'

The second smaller dataframe is df2 and contains 2 columns, 'old_column', 'new_column'.

Comment: Let me know when you've given sample data and an example of what expect the output to look like.  Read [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [***HowToAsk***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I'll gladly remove my down vote once this is included.

Comment: I have mentioned dimensions of both the dataframes in the question. I don't know how to construct tables in the interface of stackoverflow. Otherwise i would have done that. I edited the question 3 times to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Where do I get the information that specifies which row to update?

Comment: Also, you can paste data as text directly into the question.  Someone will help out with an edit if you format it wrong.

Comment: There are 2 dataframes. One with 1000 rows and other with 10 rows and we are supposed to replace rows that match the rows of second dataframe.

Comment: Match how?  You haven't made that clear.  What qualifies as a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method of pandas.Series.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'old_column':[1,2,3,4]})
# df1
#    old_column
# 0           1
# 1           2
# 2           3
# 3           4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'old_column':[2,4], 'new_column':[20,40]})
# df2
#    new_column  old_column
# 0          20           2
# 1          40           4

df1.old_column.replace(df2.set_index('old_column')['new_column'], inplace=True)
# df1 after replacement
#    old_column
# 0           1
# 1          20
# 2           3
# 3          40
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I remember sending you a message on facebook regarding some Kaggle query. Good to see you here.